# Print format cannot fix position in the div html

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a problem printing image in certain position formats. I need to put every 8 images on 1 page to show in the print preview.

I use below this sample coding this format to do the setting for every div image position，because 4 rows on 1 page, so I've tried to use 100% divide 4, then get the height value is 25%, but it cannot work in the print preview second page :

```html
<div style="height:25%;width:45%;display:inline-block;">
<img style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 90%;height:100%;width:100%" id="img_8" class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle, my problem will show in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d6h3wfer/

In the jsfiddle result problem to show second page in the print preview cannot get 8 images on 1 page.

[image: images]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

*Each div style needs the same format because in the future I need to put in the PHP format to loop each picture using the same current image div style format.

Comment: I see 10 images on the first page and 8 images on the second page.

Comment: Oops. Do you have any ideas to fix every 8 pictures on 1 page?

Comment: If I have different results on the same page than you there are some dependencies like different browsers. With Firefox I have 10 images on the first page and 8 images on the second. With Chrome I have 8 images on the first page, 6 images on the second page and 4 images on the third page.

Comment: Got code can fix the div postion no matter what browser?

Comment: I don't have any clue how to solve it but which browsers do you want to support? Have you tried to use a table?

Comment: Now I use Google

Comment: Do you mean Google Chrome? Do you only support Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes. Google Chrome. But I want to be expected all browser can work.

Comment: _"But I want to be expected all browser can work."_  That's probably not possible. Usually you only support a list of browsers. It's common to add some tweaks for different browsers. I already showed you that Firefox and Chrome behave differently.

Comment: Ok. Nevermind. You try Google Chrome first. Temporary I use google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a table:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: portrait;
  }
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  height: 25%;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img id="img_8" class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/108/thumb-350-1085603.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="img_8" src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5828605.jpg">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```